# Changing row value based on previous row value given a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

Within the following loop, I want to change any `None` value to the previous rows value. My current code does this, but if there are 2 `None`'s in a row, it will only change the first one.

I've currently used `.shift()` to put the previous rows value as a new column, called `identifierOld`, which works when only 1 `None` value needs to be changed, however there are frequently more than 1 in a row which means my code doesn't work.

```
for i in indexTest6.index:
    if indexTest6.at[i, 'identifier'] == "None":
        indexTest6.at[i, 'identifier'] = indexTest6.at[i, 'identifierOld']
```

Current output:

```
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
|     requestTime     | identifier | assetType | identifierOld |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 01/04/2019 01:18:21 | 4444       | issn      | None          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:21 | 4444       |           | 4444          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:22 | None       | None      | None          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:22 | None       | None      | None          |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+---------------------+------------+------------------+---------------+
|     requestTime     | identifier |    assetType     | identifierOld |
+---------------------+------------+------------------+---------------+
| 01/04/2019 01:18:21 |   4444     | issn             | None          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:21 |   4444     |                  | 4444          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:22 |   4444     | None             | 4444          |
| 01/04/2019 01:18:22 |   4444     | None             | 4444          |
+---------------------+------------+------------------+---------------+
```

(Ideally, I'd like to be able to do it without an additional column.)

Edit:
Thanks to anky and datanovice, using the following code worked:

```
indexTest6["identifier"] = indexTest6["identifier"].fillna(method='ffill')

+-------------+------------+-----------+
| requestTime | identifier | assetType |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
| 18:21.2     |   44444443 | issn      |
| 18:21.2     |   44444443 |           |
| 18:21.9     |   44444443 | None      |
| 18:22.1     |   44444443 | None      |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: look at [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) ?

Comment: aslo `bfill()` to back fill!

Comment: Think that's done the trick, thank you.